# Failed to execute goal maven-antrun-plugin - Connection timed out on GitHub Actions

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, maven, github-actions

I'm working on a Spring Boot + React/TypeScript app which uses GitHub Actions for CI/CD. I recently added the [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired) package to configure some webpack settings without ejecting our CRA app. Everything builds and runs fine locally (albeit a bit slower), but when pushed to GitHub, the `./mvnw test` command fails after 20+ minutes with the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  20:33 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-14T16:15:52Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (default) on project main: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.8 -> org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:pom:2.2.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.2.1/maven-plugin-api-2.2.1.pom: Connection timed out (Read failed) -> [Help 1]
Error:  
Error:  To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Error:  Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Error:  
Error:  For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error:  [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

This is the GitHub Actions `workflow.yml` file we're using:

```yml
name: Java CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD}}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 11
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: ./mvnw test

  deploy:
    needs: test
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD}}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.4.6
        with:
          heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
          heroku_app_name: "rocketden"
          heroku_email: "email@gmail.com"
```

Here is our `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.rocketden</groupId>
  <artifactId>main</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>main</name>
  <description>Our description</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- WebSocket, STOMP, SockJS dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Basic Spring framework dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Enable ability to add Entity, Id, GeneratedValue tags -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- exclude tomcat jdbc connection pool, use HikariCP -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MySQL database -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Lombok dependency to use Getters, Setters -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Encryption for database configuration -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging dependency for testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- H2 database for testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Gson, convert Java objects to JSON -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hikari Connection Pool -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
      <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JUnit testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--  Model Mapper used to convert between DTOs and Entities  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
      <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <workingDirectory>frontend</workingDirectory>
          <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <nodeVersion>v14.8.0</nodeVersion>
              <npmVersion>6.14.8</npmVersion>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>npm run build</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>run build</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/public">
                  <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/frontend/build" />
                </copy>
              </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

And here is our `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^5.4.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/react-splitter-layout": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/sockjs-client": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/stompjs": "^2.3.4",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-monaco-editor": "^0.40.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-splitter-layout": "^4.0.0",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.5.0",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.75",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.34.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.34.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the next person who runs into this -- this is basically just an issue with Azure SNAT and Maven interacting. Maven internally pools connections and Azure's SNAT closes them in a way that Java kinda can't see, and Github Actions (since GitHub is owned by Microsoft) runs in Azure.

Anyway -- the fix with current Maven versions is to set a Maven parameter to dial down the TTL on the connection pool. If you need to use an older version, there are some other parameters you can use.

So I added an env var to my workflow:

```yaml
MAVEN_OPTS: '-Dmaven.wagon.httpconnectionManager.ttlSeconds=120'
```

See also:

- [Configuring Maven](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html) if you don't want to use MAVEN_OPTS
- [WAGON-545](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WAGON-545?focusedCommentId=16755035&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16755035) and [WAGON-486](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WAGON-486) if you want more information about the issue
- [GH Actions Virtual Environments #1499](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/1499) for a bit more on the GH side of things